# OpenTBSBundle - Template not found

Tags: symfony, templates, powerpoint, opentbs

```
// get the service
$TBS = $this->container->get('opentbs');
// load your template
$template = __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/tbs-templates/klinik_template.pptx';
$TBS->LoadTemplate($template, OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
// send the file
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD, 'klinik.pptx');
```

I dont know how to load the template. I get this error:
TinyButStrong Error OpenTBS Plugin: The template '/home/chuebert/Web/garmanzky/repu/src/Bundle/UserBundle/Controller/../../../../web/tbs-templates/klinik_template.pptx' cannot be found. The process is ending, unless you set NoErr property to true.

I dont find help in the documentation of http://www.tinybutstrong.com/. 
I dont understand how to load my pptx file.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message simply means that OpenTBS (and thus PHP) cannot found the template file at `'/home/chuebert/Web/garmanzky/repu/src/Bundle/UserBundle/Controller/../../../../web/tbs-templates/klinik_template.pptx'`.
You have to check if it is a correct path for your template.

Comment: The path is correct. I dont know where the problem is :(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I have set the rights with chmod -R 775 tbs-templates/